# when use AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-Regular.ttf font warn

Tags: fonts

version pdfbox 3.0.0

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, new File("E:\\tmp\\AlibabaPuHuiTi-3-55-Regular.ttf"));
```

org.apache.fontbox.ttf.gsub.GlyphSubstitutionDataExtractor putNewSubstitutionEntry
警告: For the newGlyph: 658, newValue: [19] is trying to override the oldValue: 658

i except  is not warn

Comment: This is just a warning. Don't bother about it, unless you use GSUB features (currently only supported for Indian and some latin ligatures)